# constrain space where div can randomly spawn, Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, random

I have an element in Jquery that moves an image to a random location on the page using a mouseover event:

```
$('#rand_pos').mouseover(function() {
 var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth
 var bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
 var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyWidth));
 var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyHeight));
 // var posLog = document.getElementById('pos_log');
 var posXY = 'x: ' + randPosX + '<br />' + 'y: ' + randPosY;

$('#rand_pos').css('left', randPosX);
$('#rand_pos').css('top', randPosY);
```

I don't want the images to jump off-screen to locations users would have to scroll to. Since the divs containing the images are in the body tag, I put this in my stylesheet:

```
body {
max-height: 800px;
max-width: 1280px;
}
```

But the images keep generating into areas outside the height and width I've defined. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Provide a live example. JSFiddle or SO Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You might want subtract the body size with your image size.

```
var h = $('#rand_pos').height()
var w = $('#rand_pos').width()    

var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth - w;
var bodyHeight = document.body.clientHeight - h;
var randPosX = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyWidth));
var randPosY = Math.floor((Math.random() * bodyHeight));
```

Here I make you working example code of moving the image to random location but still inside the body bound when hovered.

http://jsbin.com/nuzayenoko/1/edit